How can a Galois group $G_p$ be isomorphic to $S_n$ if it has fewer elements?
My following question is based off in the following theorems, which i recall to be true:

The degree of the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial is equal to the degree of the polynomial.
The order of the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial equals the degree of its splitting field.
If $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of prime degree with 2 non-real roots in $\mathbb{C}$, the Galois group of its splitting field is isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}_n$.

Now, suppose we have an irreducible polynomial $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ of degree 5, and let $\Sigma_f$ and $G_f$ be its splitting field and Galois group, respectively. By (1) and (2) we should have: $$[\Sigma_f]=|G_f|=5$$
By (3), we should have $G_f\cong \mathbb{S}_5$, which trivially implies
$$|G_f|=|\mathbb{S}_5|≠5$$
This is an evident contradiction, so one of the three former theorems is incorrect...
This leads to my main question: how can the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial of degree $d≥3$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}_d$ if the theory indicates that it has fewer elements?

1 is wrong. 2 and 3 are correct. If $G_f \cong S_5$ then the degree of the splitting field is $|S_5| = 5! = 120$.

@QiaochuYuan, so the dimension of $\Sigma_f$ as a vector space over the base field should be $\mathrm{Dim}(\Sigma_f)=120$?

If the Galois group is $S_5$, yes.

As others explained, the first claim does not hold in general. If you, from some other source, know that the Galois group is abelian, then the degree of the splitting field is equal to the degree. But that is somewhat rare.

The degree of the splitting field of an irreducible polynomial is generally not equal to the degree of that polynomial. That's only true if you can get the splitting field by adjoining a single root of the polynomial.

Thanks! Does this mean that, in general, the dimension of the field generated by all the roots of an irreducible polynomial as a vector space over the base field isn't the same as the polynomial's degree?

Yes.  For example, if you adjoin the real root of $f(X) = x^3 - 2$ to $\mathbb Q$, you get the field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$, which has degree $3$ over $\mathbb Q$.  However, the splitting field of $f(X)$ over $\mathbb Q$ is $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}, e^{2 \pi i/3} \sqrt[3]{2}, e^{4\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]{2})$, which has degree $6$ over $\mathbb Q$.
